# gwt-log Configurations

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I just read the [`gwt-log` Getting Started guide](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted) and found it very helpful, however I have a few questions surrounding the Loggers:

1. The SystemLogger sends output to System.err and System.out - in the context of a client-side web app running inside a browser, where will this output eventually go? Browser logs?
2. Does RemoteLogger depend on JUL or log4j? I have a homegrown slf4j binding that I like to use for all my Java backends, and would like to use it, but not sure if RemoteLogger will be incompatible with it?
3. Is it possible to have RemoteLogger hit my own LoggingServiceServlet, which could then translate the log messages coming in on the HttpServletRequest into logging statements that are compatible with my custom slf4j binding? If so, what might this config look like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html), you have a most updated documentation about the GWT logging framework

Answers to your questions:

#1 Yes it works in client side, but only when running the app in DevMode (not in production nor superdev mode). Look for the log lines in the DevMode window, or in your terminal output if you run dev-mode from the command-line.

#2 It depends on `java.util.logging`, you can change it though (see #3)

#3 Yes you can change the logging framework extending the `RemoteLoggingServiceImpl` and overriding the `logOnServer(LogRecord lr)` method.